# Weird glitch with ASP.net drawing

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi, system.drawing

I have a code that draws a few things. At the end, it draws a string. The string looks like it was copied from a text editor -- really nice! But weirdly, when I try to draw exactly same image only 10 pixels wider, the text gets blurry. When I say wider, I only mean like initializing a Bitmap with +10px width. Image still draws on the same area like those 10px were not there.

I already checked measureString. It seems fine. My first thought was that it measures wrong and shrink text width but that can't be case since I'm only passing text and font to measureString.

I already tried drawing the text then copying the whole Image to a new Bitmap only 10px wider (Image again stays the same width, the 10px are just blank space) but exactly same thing happens. I have way too much code to post it all. Any suggestions as to what could be the problem?

Example:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the images you generated? I assume you're generating an image from a string with GDI and then making it a JPEG or PNG image and linking to it from an ASP.Net page

Comment: Yup im saving png to stream,I'm putting images so you can check it out

Comment: I posted example,exact same thing happens when I save original to hard and then resize it.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably forgot about a late-on width constraint which is keeping your final picture from expanding in width correctly: in your "resized" sample the drawn text is being *shrunk*, so logic (and the proportionally wider whitespace to the right of the "resized" sample) suggests you're actually trying to fit a wider picture in the same area.